# How to create a dataframe from Array[Strings]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used rdd.collect() to create an Array and now I want to use this Array[Strings] to create a DataFrame. My test file is in the following format(separated by a pipe |).

```
TimeStamp
IdC
Name
FileName
Start-0f-fields
column01  
column02 
column03 
column04 
column05 
column06 
column07 
column08 
column010 
column11
End-of-fields
Start-of-data 
G0002B|0|13|IS|LS|Xys|Xyz|12|23|48|  
G0002A|0|13|IS|LS|Xys|Xyz|12|23|45|  
G0002x|0|13|IS|LS|Xys|Xyz|12|23|48|  
G0002C|0|13|IS|LS|Xys|Xyz|12|23|48|
End-of-data
document
```

the column name are in between Start-of-field and End-of-Field.
I want to store "| " pipe separated in different columns of Dataframe.

like below example:

```
column01  column02 column03 column04 column05 column06 column07 column08 column010 column11
G0002C      0        13       IS       LS       Xys      Xyz     12        23         48
G0002x      0        13       LS       MS       Xys      Xyz     14        300        400
```

my code :

```scala
    val rdd = sc.textFile("the above text file")
    
    val columns = rdd.collect.slice(5,16).mkString(",") //  it will hold columnnames

    val data = rdd.collect.slice(5,16)
    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(rdd.collect())
    val df = rdd1.toDf(columns)
```

but this is not giving me the above desired dataframe

Comment: You can transform the initial RDD to Dataframe. There is no need to collect the RDD

Comment: can you paste the whole code here so that it gives idea of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```scala
import spark.implicits._ // Add to use `toDS()` and `toDF()`

val rdd = sc.textFile("the above text file")
    
val columns = rdd.collect.slice(5,16) // `.mkString(",")` is not needed

val dataDS = rdd.collect.slice(5,16)
  .map(_.trim())                           // to remove whitespaces
  .map(s => s.substring(0, s.length - 1))  // to remove last pipe '|'
  .toSeq
  .toDS

val df = spark.read
  .option("header", false)
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv(dataDS)
  .toDF(columns: _*)

df.show(false)
```

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+
|column01|column02|column03|column04|column05|column06|column07|column08|column010|column11|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+
|G0002B  |0       |13      |IS      |LS      |Xys     |Xyz     |12      |23       |48      |
|G0002A  |0       |13      |IS      |LS      |Xys     |Xyz     |12      |23       |45      |
|G0002x  |0       |13      |IS      |LS      |Xys     |Xyz     |12      |23       |48      |
|G0002C  |0       |13      |IS      |LS      |Xys     |Xyz     |12      |23       |48      |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Calling `spark.read...csv()` method without **schema**, can take a long time with huge data, because of schema inferences(e,g. Additional reading).

On that case, you can specify schema like below.

```scala
/*
  column01 STRING,
  column02 STRING,
  column03 STRING,

  ...
*/
val schema = columns
  .map(c => s"$c STRING")
  .mkString(",\n")


val df = spark.read
  .option("header", false)
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .schema(schema)  // schema inferences not occurred
  .csv(dataDS)
// .toDF(columns: _*) => unnecessary when schema is specified
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns and the name of the column are fixed then you can do that as below :

```
val columns = rdd.collect.slice(5,15).mkString(",") //  it will hold columnnames
val data = rdd.collect.slice(17,21)
val d = data.mkString("\n").split('\n').toSeq.toDF()
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dd = d.withColumn("columnX",split($"value","\\|")).withColumn("column1",$"columnx".getItem(0)).withColumn("column2",$"columnx".getItem(1)).withColumn("column3",$"columnx".getItem(2)).withColumn("column4",$"columnx".getItem(3)).withColumn("column5",$"columnx".getItem(4)).withColumn("column6",$"columnx".getItem(5)).withColumn("column8",$"columnx".getItem(7)).withColumn("column10",$"columnx".getItem(8)).withColumn("column11",$"columnx".getItem(9)).drop("columnX","value")
display(dd)
```

you can see the output as below:[image]

Comment: thanks @Nikunj, this was helpful. I tried the below code and it worked:    ~~~ val data_frame = rdd.map(f => f.split("//|")).map( f=> (f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6),f(7),f(8),f(9),f(10),f(11))).toDF~~~    I was not able to use the val column for giving the column names so I had to hardcode it.

Comment: happy to hear. Can you upvote the answer if that helped you.